# Should we have a tag for ethereumj?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

EthereumJ is the Java client.

[How can configure EthereumJ to connect to the public testnet.?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/how-can-configure-ethereumj-to-connect-to-the-public-testnet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All specific implementations should get their own tag.

I guess this needs moderator attention, as you can not create [ethereumj](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethereumj) because the system thinks it's the same as [ethereumjs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethereumjs).

Comment: Exactly for the question and why I tagged this with [tag:support] :)